# different typedef of the same struct in c

Tags: c

In SequenceStack.h, I have the following code

```
#ifndef SEQUENCESTACK_H
#define SEQUENCESTACK_H

#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_MAZE_H
typedef int SElemType_Sq;
#endif

typedef struct {
    SElemType_Sq *base;
    SElemType_Sq *top;
    int stacksize;
}SqStack;
```

In SequenceStack.c, I have

```
#include "SequenceStack.h"
```

which defines a stack.

In an other program which I want to use the stack but I want to change the elemtype.

So in Maze.h I have

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_MAZE_H
#define DATASTRUCTURE_MAZE_H

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}PosType;

typedef struct {
    int ord;
    PosType seat;
    int di;
}SElemType_Sq;

#include "SequenceStack.h"
```

The SqStack changed in the debugger only int ord is affected.

If I change SequenceStack.h to

```
#ifndef SEQUENCESTACK_H
#define SEQUENCESTACK_H

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
}PosType;

typedef struct {
    int ord;
    PosType seat;
    int di;
}SElemType_Sq;

typedef struct {
    SElemType_Sq *base;
    SElemType_Sq *top;
    int stacksize;
}SqStack;
```

and put nothing in Maze.h, everything works fine.

I want to know what is going wrong and why #ifndef is not working. I can give the source code.

Comment: That smells like an ODR violation or something. You're trying to do generics/templates, which C doesn't do well.

Comment: Not clear what exactly you are asking... What were you expecting and what do you get? What do you mean by: "The SqStack changed in the debugger only int ord is affected." (maybe a comma is missing somewhere?)?

Comment: The only "generic" type in C is the pointer to anything `void *`. Perhaps you can solve your problem using `void *` (and type-casts as needed)?

Comment: Building on what @Someprogrammerdude said, if you want to write some stack code that will work for different types of objects, you might be best off storing a `void*` inside the stack. You can then create a stack for integers, a stack of structures, and so on. This is quite risky, as there's nothing to stop you pushing a string onto a stack of ints, or a struct onto a stack of floats. But it will let you re-use your stack code.

Answer (score 2):

In C (and C++), `#include` is very primitive mechanism, it is just "copy-paste" of the text in the included file, before actual compilation.

So, what happens here is, you compile your *SequenceStack.c* with the `int*` pointers. The code in the functions uses that type.

Then you pass these functions parameters, which don't match that. So it's no wonder things don't work right.

If you want "generic" stack with pointers, I suggest you use `void*` pointers to the elements in *SequenceStack*. Depending on your full code, such as you need to copy/reallocate elements, you may have to add size of element to `SqStack`.

Comment: So my understand is that it ignores the code inside #ifndef and paste the rests into Maze.h. However when complie StackSe.c the code inside #ifndef is not ignored. It is right?

Comment: Yep, though I woudln't say "ignores". The preprocessor either leaves in or removes the source code inside `#if...#else...#endif` blocks based on the condition, when it produces the actual source code which gets fed to the C compilation phase. Preprosessing phase is basically text manipulation, which happens before actual compilation phase. Compilers have switches to just do the preprosessing stage or produce the intermediate temp files, which can be helpful in solving some bugs.